# JTableHeader Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Buenas tardes,
Me gustaría saber como añadir un Header personalizado en una tabla con mas de una columna combinada, etc.

Comment: ¿Ya lo intentaste? Si no es así, primero inténtalo. ¿Tienes problemas al respecto? coloca un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de lo que tratas de hacer.

Comment: Ya lo tengo claro. Al final logre solucionar el problema

Comment: Si lo ves prudente, publica la respuesta por si le sirve a otros pero actualizando tu pregunta añadiendo más detalle.

Comment: Ya esta, ya he indicado la respuesta

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo, pero la idea era que pongas eso **como respuesta** no **como edición**. Debajo de tu pregunta hay una caja de texto para autoresponderte.

Comment: ¿Que hago? Lo cambio y lo pongo abajo?

Comment: Así es, es la idea.

Comment: Ya esta, publicada la respuesta

Comment: Genial. No olvides después de dos días, aceptar tu respuesta (para mejor organización del sitio). Saludos.

Comment: ¿Aceptar mi respuesta? En dos días quieres decir ¿que me llegará como un tipo de notificación y tendré que aceptar mi respuesta?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55525/discussion-between-barraca96-and-gustavo-garcia).

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la respuesta a la pregunta. Ya he podido lograr lo deseado.

Aquí están los pasos:

## Creación de la clase ColumnGroup

```js
public class ColumnGroup {
  protected TableCellRenderer renderer;
  protected Vector v;
  protected String text;
  protected int margin=0;

  public ColumnGroup(String text) {
    this(null,text);
  }

  public ColumnGroup(TableCellRenderer renderer,String text) {
    if (renderer == null) {
      this.renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                         boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    if (header != null) {
      setForeground(header.getForeground());
      setBackground(header.getBackground());
      setFont(header.getFont());
    }
          setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    return this;
        }
      };
    } else {
      this.renderer = renderer;
    }
    this.text = text;
    v = new Vector();
  }

  
  /**
   * @param obj    TableColumn or ColumnGroup
   */
  public void add(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) { return; }
    v.addElement(obj);
  }

  
  /**
   * @param c    TableColumn
   * @param v    ColumnGroups
   */
  public Vector getColumnGroups(TableColumn c, Vector g) {
    g.addElement(this);
    if (v.contains(c)) return g;    
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
        Vector groups = 
          (Vector)((ColumnGroup)obj).getColumnGroups(c,(Vector)g.clone());
        if (groups != null) return groups;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
    
  public TableCellRenderer getHeaderRenderer() {
    return renderer;
  }
    
  public void setHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer) {
    if (renderer != null) {
      this.renderer = renderer;
    }
  }
    
  public Object getHeaderValue() {
    return text;
  }
  
  public Dimension getSize(JTable table) {
    Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        table, getHeaderValue(), false, false,-1, -1);
    int height = comp.getPreferredSize().height; 
    int width  = 0;
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof TableColumn) {
        TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)obj;
        width += aColumn.getWidth();
        width += margin;
      } else {
        width += ((ColumnGroup)obj).getSize(table).width;
      }
    }
    return new Dimension(width, height);
  }

  public void setColumnMargin(int margin) {
    this.margin = margin;
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
        ((ColumnGroup)obj).setColumnMargin(margin);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Creación de la clase GroupableTableHeader

```js
public class GroupableTableHeader extends JTableHeader {
  private static final String uiClassID = "GroupableTableHeaderUI";
  protected Vector columnGroups = null;
    
  public GroupableTableHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
    super(model);
    setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
    setReorderingAllowed(false);
  }
  public void updateUI(){
   setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
  }
  
  public void setReorderingAllowed(boolean b) {
    reorderingAllowed = false;
  }
    
  public void addColumnGroup(ColumnGroup g) {
    if (columnGroups == null) {
      columnGroups = new Vector();
    }
    columnGroups.addElement(g);
  }

  public Enumeration getColumnGroups(TableColumn col) {
    if (columnGroups == null) return null;
    Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
      Vector v_ret = (Vector)cGroup.getColumnGroups(col,new Vector());
      if (v_ret != null) { 
  return v_ret.elements();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  
  public void setColumnMargin() {
    if (columnGroups == null) return;
    int columnMargin = getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
    Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
      cGroup.setColumnMargin(columnMargin);
    }
  }
  
}
```

## Creación de la clase GroupableTableHeaderUI

```js
public class GroupableTableHeaderUI extends BasicTableHeaderUI {
  
  public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
    if (header.getColumnModel() == null) return;
    ((GroupableTableHeader)header).setColumnMargin();
    int column = 0;
    Dimension size = header.getSize();
    Rectangle cellRect  = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    int columnMargin = header.getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
    
    Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      cellRect.height = size.height;
      cellRect.y      = 0;
      TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)enumeration.nextElement();
      Enumeration cGroups = ((GroupableTableHeader)header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);
      if (cGroups != null) {
        int groupHeight = 0;
        while (cGroups.hasMoreElements()) {
          ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)cGroups.nextElement();
          Rectangle groupRect = (Rectangle)h.get(cGroup);
          if (groupRect == null) {
            groupRect = new Rectangle(cellRect);
            Dimension d = cGroup.getSize(header.getTable());
            groupRect.width  = d.width;
            groupRect.height = d.height;    
            h.put(cGroup, groupRect);
          }
          paintCell(g, groupRect, cGroup);
          groupHeight += groupRect.height;
          cellRect.height = size.height - groupHeight;
          cellRect.y      = groupHeight;
        }
      }      
      cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin;
      if (cellRect.intersects(clipBounds)) {
        paintCell(g, cellRect, column);
      }
      cellRect.x += cellRect.width;
      column++;
    }
  }

  private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int columnIndex) {
    TableColumn aColumn = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
    TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
    //revised by Java2s.com
    renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
          JLabel header = new JLabel();
            header.setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
            header.setBackground(table.getTableHeader().getBackground());
            header.setFont(table.getTableHeader().getFont());

          header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          header.setText(value.toString());
          header.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
            return header;
        }
    
    };
    Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(),false, false, -1, columnIndex);
        
        c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
      
    rendererPane.add(c);
    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, c, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
        cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
  }

  private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect,ColumnGroup cGroup) {
    TableCellRenderer renderer = cGroup.getHeaderRenderer();
      //revised by Java2s.com
     // if(renderer == null){
//      return ;
  //    }

    Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
      header.getTable(), cGroup.getHeaderValue(),false, false, -1, -1);
    rendererPane.add(component);
    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, component, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
        cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
  }

  private int getHeaderHeight() {
    int height = 0;
    TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
    for(int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
      TableColumn aColumn = columnModel.getColumn(column);
      TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
      //revised by Java2s.com
      if(renderer == null){
      return 60;
      }
      
      Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false, false,-1, column);
      int cHeight = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
      Enumeration e = ((GroupableTableHeader)header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);      
      if (e != null) {
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
          ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
          cHeight += cGroup.getSize(header.getTable()).height;
        }
      }
      height = Math.max(height, cHeight);
    }
    return height;
  }

  private Dimension createHeaderSize(long width) {
    TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
    width += columnModel.getColumnMargin() * columnModel.getColumnCount();
    if (width > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
      width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return new Dimension((int)width, getHeaderHeight());
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
    long width = 0;
    Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)enumeration.nextElement();
      width = width + aColumn.getPreferredWidth();
    }
    return createHeaderSize(width);
  }
}
```

## Creación de la clase GroupableTableHeaderExample

```js
public class GroupableHeaderExample extends JPanel {

  public GroupableHeaderExample(ArrayList<Contador> contadores) {
    JTable table = null;
    
    //Se crea el modelo de la cabecera
    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
    String objectos [][] = new String[contadores.size()][3];
    
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<contadores.size();i++){
        System.out.println(contadores.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<objectos.length;i++){
        objectos[i][0] = contadores.get(i).getFecha();
        objectos[i][1] = String.valueOf(contadores.get(i).getLectura());
        objectos[i][2] = "0"; 
    }
    
    // Mostrar los datos de dentro de array bidimensional.
    for(int i=0;i<objectos.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<objectos[i].length;j++){
            System.out.println(objectos[i][j].toString());
        }
    }
    
    //Insertar los datos en el modelo
    dm.setDataVector(objectos,new Object[]{"Fecha","Lectura","Consumo"});

    //Creación de la tabla con el modelo de cabecera principal
    table = new JTable(dm) {
      protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
          return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
      }
    };

    //Se crea un segundo modelo
    TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();//Se coge el modelo del header principal
    ColumnGroup contador = new ColumnGroup(contadores.get(0).getSerialNumber());//Se crea un grupo
    contador.add(cm.getColumn(1));
    contador.add(cm.getColumn(2));
    GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader)table.getTableHeader();
    header.addColumnGroup(contador);

    
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    this.add(scroll);
    setSize( 600, 450);
    
  }
}
```

Con estas clases creadas, ahora pasamos a la creación de la clase main

## Creación de la clase main

```js
public class main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form main
     */
    public main() {
        initComponents();
        
        //Crear el arrayList
        ArrayList<Contador> contadores = new ArrayList<Contador>();
        
        //Insertar datos al arrayList
        contadores.add(new Contador("P44152F", "10:00:00", "21/03/2017", 100.00));
        contadores.add(new Contador("R44152F", "11:00:00", "22/03/2017", 99.00));

        //Se crea el panel con los datos correspondientes
        GroupableHeaderExample panel = new GroupableHeaderExample(contadores);
        jPanelTabla.add(panel);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanelTabla = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelTablaLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelTabla);
        jPanelTabla.setLayout(jPanelTablaLayout);
        jPanelTablaLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelTablaLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 683, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanelTablaLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelTablaLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 311, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(95, 95, 95)
                .addComponent(jPanelTabla, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(501, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jPanelTabla, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(240, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        System.out.println(info.getName());
                        if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                            try {
                                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                new main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelTabla;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Con esto he podido solucionar el problema. Aquí os dejo una captura de la ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]